# Is it possible using the POST verb to ApiController still map URI to method's parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible using the POST verb to ApiController still map URI to method's parameters.

Something like this:

```
[Route("Backoffice/CancelRequest/{0}")]
public void CancelRequest(int requestId, [FromBody]RemeltServiceMessageBindingModel message)
{
            log(message);
            service.CancelRequest(requestId);
}
```

I can't arrange it working...

Answer (score 0):

Are you telling it is a POST request?

```
[HttpPost, Route("Backoffice/CancelRequest/{0}")]
```